# resizable header in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to make resizable header but it breaks.
I am trying to clone twitter profile,
I think logic is right but can I know why this one is not working?
I made HStack and try to hide it but when I scroll back it can't come back.
Tried with GeometryReader
Please help me, thanks

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    // change views
    @State var isHide = false
    
    @State private var selectionFilter: TweetFilterViewModel = .tweets
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            
            //hiding
            if isHide == false {
                headerView
                
                actionButtons
                
                userInfoDetails
            }
            
            tweetFilterBar
                .padding(0)
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    
                    GeometryReader { reader -> AnyView in
                        
                        let yAxis = reader.frame(in: .global).minY
                        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
                        
                        if yAxis < height && !isHide {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isHide = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if yAxis > 0 && isHide {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isHide = false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return AnyView(
                            Text("")
                                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                        )
                    }
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                    
                    ForEach(0...9, id: \.self) { _ in
                        TweetRowView()
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}

struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}

extension ProfileView {
    var headerView: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            Color(.systemBlue)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Button {

                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 16)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .position(x: 30, y: 12)
                }

            }
            
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 72, height: 72)
                .offset(x: 16, y: 24)
        }.frame(height: 96)
    }
    
    var actionButtons: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12){
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "bell.badge")
                .font(.title3)
                .padding(6)
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.75))
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("Edit Profile")
                    .font(.subheadline).bold()
                    .accentColor(.black)
                    .padding(10)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.75))
            }

        }
        .padding(.trailing)
    }
    
    var userInfoDetails: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack(spacing: 4) {
                Text("Heath Legdet")
                    .font(.title2).bold()
                
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.seal.fill")
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBlue))
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 2)
            
            Text("@joker")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            
            Text("Your mom`s favorite villain")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(.vertical)
            
            HStack(spacing: 24) {
                Label("Gothem.NY", systemImage: "mappin.and.ellipse")
                
                Label("www.thejoker.com", systemImage: "link")
            }
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            
            HStack(spacing: 24) {
                HStack {
                    Text("807")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .bold()
                    
                    Text("following")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("200")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .bold()
                    
                    Text("followers")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    var tweetFilterBar: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(TweetFilterViewModel.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(selectionFilter == item ? .semibold : .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(selectionFilter == item ? .black : .gray)
                    
                    
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(Color(.clear))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                        
                        if selectionFilter == item {
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(Color(.systemBlue))
                                .frame(height: 3)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "filter", in: animation)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        self.selectionFilter = item
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the animation between show and hide is running, the `GeometryReader` is still calculating values – which lets the view jump between show and hide – and gridlock.

You can introduce a new `@State var isInTransition = false` that checks if a show/hide animation is in progress and check for that. You set it to `true` at the beginning of the animation and to `false` 0.5 secs later.

Also I believe the switch height is not exactly 1/2 of the screen size.

[image]

So add a new state var:

```
    @State var isInTransition = false
```

and in GeometryReader add:

```
                    GeometryReader { reader -> AnyView in
                        
                        let yAxis = reader.frame(in: .global).minY
                        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
                        
                        if yAxis < 350 && !isHide && !isInTransition {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                isInTransition = true
                                withAnimation {
                                    isHide = true
                                }
                            }
                            // wait for animation to finish
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                isInTransition = false
                            }
                        } else if yAxis > 0 && isHide && !isInTransition {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                isInTransition = true
                                withAnimation {
                                    isHide = false
                                }
                            }
                            // wait for animation to finish
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                                isInTransition = false
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return AnyView(
                            // displaying values for test purpose
                            Text("\(yAxis) - \(isInTransition ? "true" : "false")").foregroundColor(.red)
//                                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                        )
                    }
```